# Can't clone git project with Netbeans IDE, but CLI works

Tags: git, netbeans, confluence, git-clone

I'm trying to work with GIT (confluence) using NetBeans as IDE.
I correctly (I think) added connection string:

```
http://git-repo:7990/scm/riw/php-project.git
```

with username and password fields configured with my credentials

I followed the steps in [this](https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/ide/git_nb_ssh_screencast.html) Netbeans official video

But once I get tho what I suppose is the last step I get this message:

`http://dds@git-repo:7990/scm/riw/php-project.git Starting read stage without written request data pending is not supported`

On my local system I find the project folder with inner .git folder, but there are no project files.

with CLI running:

```
git clone http://git-repo:7990/scm/riw/php-project.git
```

I'm asked for username and password then all data is downloaded.

My question is: what should I do to make netbeans git plugin work as supposed to?

I'm running the last version of netbeans: *Apache NetBeans IDE 11.0 (Build incubator-netbeans-release-404-on-20190319)*

My OS is *Xubuntu*, with O*racle Java 12* and *php 7.2*

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround, since the CLI git clone does work:

- clone it manually,
- then import the project in your NetBeans, and do check the fetch/pull/push works that way.

May be it is a [certificate issue to be accepted](https://sourceforge.net/p/forge/site-support/8350/#a81a).